# HTTP proxy over Tor

Tags: windows, socks, https, proxy

Can somebody suggest me some HTTP proxy app for Windows?

There are a few apps I wanna use over Tor, but they don't support SOCKS proxy, only HTTP proxy.

So I need an HTTP proxy that's able to be itself a SOCKS proxy client, to be a bridge between these apps and Tor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polipo is the best choice! Here is an [official website](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) and [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/jech/polipo)